# Build error when deploying to Vercel (builds fine locally)

Tags: javascript, graphql, next.js, vercel

I'm developing the frontend of a website with Next.js, which pulls in data from a Wordpress site via graphql, more precisely with the help of the WPGraphQL plugin. Everything works fine locally, including building the app; however when I try to deploy it to Vercel using the `vercel` command in the Vercel CLI (or by pushing to Git), as soon as a request to the graphql server is made the build fails due to the following error:

> GraphQL Request must include at least one of those two parameters:
> "query" or "queryId"

Basically, the call to the server works but it's like the query document is not passed. However, the same code works fine locally!

Here's the helper function that I use to wrap all graphql requests:

```
export const graphqlRequest = async ( key, query, queryVars, authToken = null ) => {
    
    try {

        const backendUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_URL
        
        const res = await fetch( `${backendUrl}`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                ...( authToken ? { "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}` } : {} )
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                query: query, // The query here seems not to be seen when deploying to Vercel...
                variables: queryVars
            })
        })

        const resData = await res.json()

        if( ! res.ok ) throw new WpApiErr( resData ) 

        const { data, errors: err } = resData || {}
    
        if( err && ! data ) {
            throw new WPGraphQLErr( err ) // This is when the error is thrown! 
        }

        return {
            data: data || null,
            err: err || null,
        }

    } catch( err ) {

        throw( err )
    
    }

}
```

Then I use it something like this:

```
export const fetchPostsStaticPaths = async () => {

    const query = `
        {
            posts( first: 10 ) {
                nodes {
                    slug
                    mainCat
                }
            }   
        }
    `   
    
    const { data } = await graphqlRequest( "/posts-paths", query ) || {}

    // Do something with data 

}
```

I tried hardcoding the query document directly in `graphqlRequest`, but that didn't help...